Isomorphism of Virasoro Algebra with Different Highest Weights
Recently I was reading the big yellow book on "Conformal Field Theory" by P. Francesco et.al, and in appendix 8.A.1, it defined a covariant linear map for fusion process among irreducible highest-weight modules:
$$
\mathcal{F}: M(c,h_{0},;x_{0}) \otimes M(c,h_{1},;x_{1}) \to M(c,h,;x)
$$
and blow that mentioned that:

we deal with three isomorphic- but not identical- copies of the Virasoro algebra, it is not surprising that the product of highest-weight states in
$M(c,h_{0}; x_{0}) \otimes M(c,h_{1};x_{1})$
does not correspond to just the highest-weight state
in
$M(c,h;x)$
, but rather to an infinite linear combination.

My question is why Virasoro algebra with different highest-weights are isomorphic?
How this isomorphic representations (if they are) map to each other?
